# Why is this ajax call being made even though it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

i have this validation script im working on but cant see why im having an issue.

You can see that i have a check = false / true, check before it runs the ajax call.

However, even if a field is empty and check is set to false, it is still running the call.

so:

```
// JavaScript - Update Password AJAX

$(document).ready(function () {

    // When the form is submitted
    $('.updatepasswordform').submit(function () {

        var check = true;

        // Get the values
        var password1 = $("input[name=password1]").val();
        var password2 = $("input[name=password2]").val();
        var newpassword = $("input[name=newpassword]").val();

        /* Password Validation */

        // If fields are empty
        if (password1 === '') {
            check = false;
            $("input[name=password1]").css('border', 'solid 2px red');
        }

        // If fields are empty
        if (password2 === '') {
            check = false;
            $("input[name=password2]").css('border', 'solid 2px red');
        }

        // If fields are empty
        if (newpassword === '') {
            check = false;
            $("input[name=newpassword]").css('border', 'solid 2px red');
        }

        if (check = true) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process/updatepassword.php",
                data: $(".updatepasswordform").serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

                    /* Checks for database validation, removed for space saving */

                }

            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using assignment, `=`, instead of comparison, `==`, to test `check`. Instead of this...

```
if (check = true) {
```

you meant to write this:

```
if (check == true) {
```

This is a common pitfall. It's completely valid to assign `true` to `check` inside the condition of an `if` statement, though in this case it's not what you meant to do. The result of `check = true` is *also* `true` (which allows for parallel assignment, `a = b = c = true`, to work), so in essence you're doing `if (true)`. This is desirable, though often the source of trouble when used accidentally. The general use is to assign the result of an expression to a temporary variable which is scoped to the `if` statement.

Basically, instead of this...

```
var result = expensiveCalculation()
if (result) {
  // do something with result
}
```

... it lets you write this:

```
if (result = expensiveCalculation()) {
  // do something with result
}
```

Note:

In this particular case, when you're testing against boolean `true`/`false`, it's always preferable to simply write `if (check)` or `if (!check)` instead of explicitly comparing using `==`.

Note 2:

"check" is a particularly bad variable name. Your variables should be expressive; I should know what it does, without the aid of comments. In this case, I'd have called it *at least* `valid`, or possibly `formIsValid`, or invert your check and use `var errors = false` and `if (!errors)`.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth information, really helps me learn. Working with both php and js currently and = / == / === is something i need to get to grips with! im sure it will be second nature in the future though!

Answer (score 2):

`if (check = true)` is assignment. You need a check.

```
if (check == true) {
```

Or as JasonP mentions, just

```
if (check) {
```

Comment: Or really, just `if (check) {`

Comment: Thanks, sorted it! Always something simple!

Comment: Yeah, sometimes they are really  hard to spot.

Answer (score 1):

You are only using a single equals in your if statement. Change it to this

```
if (check == true) {
```

or even better

```
if (check) {
```

Comment: Splendid, new it would be something simple!

So in any if query, if you just have the variable inside () it is the same as being true.

Noted. :)

Comment: Many programming languages behave in that way. Very helpful indeed.